# Script works when run from browser, but not in CronTab?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, cron

i'm running ubuntu.

my cron job:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/cron; php -f sendQueuedEmails.php
```

is set but is not running. when i run:

```
http://localhost/cron/sendQueuedEmails.php
```

inside firefox it works perfectly, but when i run:

```
php sendQueuedEmails.php
```

from the terminal, i get **no errors and no output**.

what could be the problem?